# OpenCart 4.0.1.1 in spite of use SEO URLs and rewrite configured always add ?route=product/product to the path

Tags: opencart

This is OpenCart 4.0.1.1.
Mod rewrite is configured and working properly.
The .htaccess file is present and works (I've checked it)
The "Use SEO URLs" in the Shop settings is set to ON.

But still in the shop catalog every product have link like this:

```
https://www.myshop.com/product_name?route=product/product
```

When I delete ?route=product/product from url so it is like this:

```
https://www.myshop.com/product_name
```

It works perfectly well.

The same is with categories. In the category list all categories have links like this:

```
https://www.myshop.com/category_name?route=product/category
```

however if is manually put https://www.myshop.com/category_name it works perfectly.

Did I miss something? Is there any setting hidden somewhere?